# Restaurant "TO" another world?

Tags: word-choice

> [image]

In this anime, some certain magical doors appear wherever they pleased and let in the people of fantasy world to the restaurant in our side. But the title's bugging me. Why do they have to put 'to' instead of 'in'? If I put 'in' there, would it be awkward? Could you give me some examples that have the same usage of that 'to'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a distinction between a door (restaurant, opening or similar) **to** another world and one **in** another world.

The preposition **to** indicates that the place or object concerned serves to transport a person from one world to another. It's like a bridge. The visitor enters from a particular world and is transported metaphorically into a different world - one that is more beautiful or strange or mysterious or whatever.

In this sense, diving equipment transports a diver from a land world to a sea world by allowing the diver to explore the world under the water.

The preposition **in** indicates that the door is already to be found in a different world and allows a visitor to enter (or leave) the venue concerned in that particular world - but not to leave the world itself.

So I might say that:

> Explorers found a hidden door **to** the tomb of a pharaoh

indicating that the door enabled them to enter the tomb of the pharaoh from a passage or point outside the tomb.

Alternatively:

> Explorers found a hidden door **in** the tomb of the pharaoh

indicates that they were already inside the tomb when they discovered a door that led elsewhere.

Thus in your example a door **to** another world suggests that the restaurant offers diners an experience that is totally new to them. A door **in** another world would suggest that they were already in the other world when they came across a door that led elsewhere within this world. This is not the idea that the restaurateurs wish to convey.

Comment: +1 Experiencing the food and ambience of this restaurant will transport you **to** another world. The phrase is meant figuratively, not literally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "in":

> Where is the restaurant? **In** another word.

But the *door* is "**to**" or "**into**" the restaurant *in* another world.

Perhaps, they take the restaurant as a kind of road which leads somewhere... (*to* another world). That's the only explanation I can give. Note that this use of "to" after "restaurant" is definitely non-standard because usually restaurants don't perform the function of a door or a road.